# Jquery insert blocks in a fixed width container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this is quite old style, Im trying to achieve this [see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta6ag.gif)

I tried using this.

Jquery

```
var i = 0;

var appendDiv = setInterval(function(){
  if (i === 7) {

    clearInterval(appendDiv);

  } else (
    $(".output").append("<div class='box'style='width:10%;'></div>")
  )
  i++
}, 1000)`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hp3Lj9da/

Any help would be appreciated!

TIA

Comment: You don't need to apply fixed width, use `flexbox` instead.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it just with CSS using `flex`:

```js
var i = 0;

var appendDiv = setInterval(function(){ 
  if (i === 7) {
    clearInterval(appendDiv);
  } else (
    $(".output").append("<div class='box'></div>")
  )
  i++
}, 1000)
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.output {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: I think you don't even need `space-around` because there's no space left to distribute in-between the children. Also, why do you put `width: 100%` to .box? When there are two of them, they can't both have 100% with. Use `flex-grow:1` instead.

Comment: @JeremyThille I added `space-around` and the `width` just to show a nicer example, but yes it is not really needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the fixed width from `.box` and give `flex: 1`. Also use `display: flex` for `output`

```js
var i = 0;
var appendDiv = setInterval(function () {
  if (i === 7) {
    clearInterval(appendDiv);
  } else $(".output").append("<div class='box'></div>");
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.box:hover{background:red;
}

.output{
  display: flex;
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  flex: 1;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, why `display:inline-block` though? It's useless

Comment: Yes it can be removed

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to position the `div`s.

You can achieve the hover effect with the `:hover` pseudo class.

```js
var i = 0;

var appendDiv = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === 7) {
    clearInterval(appendDiv);
  } else {
    $(".container").append("<div></div>");
  }
  i++
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: #0B2CFF;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>h
```